# How to create connection?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-extensions

On this page https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions
I found how to use SQLite-Net Extensions. But in order to start using it, there is a call:

```
var db = Utils.CreateConnection();
```

How to implement this method?

Comment: Add it in your constructor?

Comment: How to implement method CreateConnection()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SQLite NET](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#synchronous-api) docs

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, myDBFilePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

I too would love to know how to implement Utils.CreateConnection()

Ah c'mon guys give us a clue

the current answer posted (with some apparent condescension  quoting 'from SQlite net docs' as if to say its simple...idiot!) helps not one little bit if one is using SQLite-net in xamarin forms

the statement "var xxx= new SQLiteConnection(dbp);"
  takes only the path of the DB and does not call for a 'platform' parameter when using the above assembly

To what namespace does Utils.CreateConnection() belong - what assemblies need to be included if using Frank Kruegers SQLite-net.pcl in Xamarin forms 
questions ??
1) Does the sqlite-net-extensions work with sqlite-net-pcl in Xam forms ?
2) why does there need to be such a proliferation of SQLite assemblies some with uppercase some with dashes 
3) why is SQL and c# such a  tower of Babel

Dya know it would be really useful if on such fora as these or in so called helpful 'code snippets' the Assemblies used were included - even if it is simply including the 'using' statements.
Sorry for the grumpy post but surely its a fair question

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old thread but the answer can be found from the author repo:

https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/Tests/IntegrationTests/Utils.cs

```
public static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
        {
#if USING_MVVMCROSS
            return new TouchSqliteConnectionFactory().GetConnection(DatabaseFilePath);
#else
            var con = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseFilePath);
            raw.sqlite3_trace(con.Handle, Log, null);
            return con;
#endif
        }
```